# SAS function difference with double quotes and single quotes parameter string

Tags: string, sas

in Sas, below case 1 with single quotes works well, but case 2 with double quotes string parameters

```
case 1:
    data _null_;
    a = lowcase('ABC');
    run;

case 2:
    data _null_;
    a = lowcase("ABC");
    run;

825   data _null_;
826   a = lowcase("ABC");
                  -
                  386
                  200
                  76
ERROR 386-185: Expecting an arithmetic expression.
ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.
ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.*

827   run;
```

Comment: You sure you don't have "smart quote" characters in your code?

Comment: I think smart quote is almost certainly the issue, if the above is mostly faithfully reproduced (smart quote = the “ ” characters different from " ")

Comment: Greatvia, you'll need to post something that actually causes the error when run to get any further help here.  Since the above does not cause the error, it is not helpful in solving your problem.

Comment: Also check earlier in your log for unbalanced quotes.  If you forget and leave open a set of quotes then SAS can get very confused about what are commands and what are quoted string literals.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have rerun your code and it worked absolutely fine on SAS 9.3

```
 data _null_; a = lowcase('ABC'); put  a;   run;

 abc 

 NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
       real time           0.00 seconds
       cpu time            0.00 seconds


 data _null_; a = lowcase("ABC");   put a;  run;

 abc 

 NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
       real time           0.00 seconds
       cpu time            0.00 seconds
```

Looking at the logs, you have 800 lines of code before that. Looking at the error, the second case scenario interprets "ABC" as as a macro variable. Macro variables are not interpreted in the single quotes, which is why the first case works fine.

I expect that you have changed the code before posting it here and in your real code, you would have something like "lowcase("ABCD&EDGR") with ampersand in it. If that's the case, then the ampersand is the reason why SAS thinking you are passing a macro variable to it. Use single quotes if you don't want SAS to try to interpret ampersand as indicator for macro variable.

Comment: I am using SAS9.3 too.

Comment: is it my computer' issue? I will try to reboot and try again.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have "&" ampersands in your string that your are lowercasing? That should be your issue.

Comment: Of cause. I met such error in my code, then i create this simple case to test, same error. i have to try to use single quotes as possible as i can.

Comment: i made a update to the register key today in order to get the correct column type while import the excel.

Comment: I did change the value of ‘TypeGuessRows’ in my registry from 8 to 0. Not sure if any relationship with this error.

Comment: I can't see how that registry change would have an impact. you can always revert the change and try again. I am shocked that sas interprets simple string like "ABC" without ampersand as a macro variable. I would say SAS SUPPORT would need to know about it. You can always file a ticket with them if you have support.

Comment: @VasilijNevlev Doubt it's macro variables, the error is in the double quote side, and on the first character (unless the error is unfaithfully reproduced).  In any event - the error is not that SAS sees it as macro variable.  It is SAS sees invalid syntax, which points to smart quotes or something similar.

Comment: After i reboot my laptop, the issue is resolve. As you point, both double quotes and single quotes can work well. It is weird, don't know how is happened. Thank you for your time and help!!

Answer (score 0):

This is a fake issue. 
After system reboot, the issue is disappear.
Both single quotes and double quotes can work same.